# Get list of objects from s3 bucket (min.io or amazon) using promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, es6-promise, minio

I am trying to get a list of object name from s3 bucket using min.io javascript API (https://docs.min.io/docs/javascript-client-api-reference#listObjectsV2). The API returns a stream. However, I always get an empty list.

The example of the dataStream is:

```
{
  name: 'sample-mp4-file-1.mp4',
  lastModified: 2020-10-14T02:35:38.308Z,
  etag: '5021b3b7c402468d5b018a8b4a2b448a',
  size: 10546620
}
{
  name: 'sample-mp4-file-2.mp4',
  lastModified: 2020-10-14T15:54:44.672Z,
  etag: '5021b3b7c402468d5b018a8b4a2b448a',
  size: 10546620
}
```

My function

```
public async listFiles(
        bucketName: string,
        prefix?: string
    ): Promise<string[]> {
        const objectsList = [];
        await minioClient.listObjectsV2(bucketName, "", true, "", function(
            err,
            dataStream
        ) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error listFiles: ", err);
                return;
            }

            console.log("Succesfully get data");


            dataStream.on("data", function(obj) {
                objectsList.push(obj.name);
            });

            dataStream.on("error", function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });

            dataStream.on("end", function(e) {
                console.log("Total number of objects: ", objectsList.length);
            });
        });

        return objectsList;
    }
```

Expected output is a list object name, [sample-mp4-file-1.mp4, sample-mp4-file-2.mp4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, `listObjectsV2()` is returning a stream, not a promise.  Therefore, `await` is returning immediately, before `objectsList` will contain anything.

The API you're using has to support Promises if you want to `await` them.

You could work around this by doing something like this:

```
const objectsList = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const objectsListTemp = [];
  const stream = minioClient.listObjectsV2(bucketName, '', true, '');
  
  stream.on('data', obj => objectsListTemp.push(obj.name));
  stream.on('error', reject);
  stream.on('end', () => {
    resolve(objectsListTemp);
  });
});
```

Comment: this works like charm! thanks for the help. I also found a slight different approach
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron